# Constructing new lists using Table

Tags: list-manipulation

I tried to modify an old notebook to show a spreadsheet style output in a table.  I am not getting any errors when it runs, so I think the data I am gathering and the new variables I added, `t` and `y`, are there correctly.  I removed the `colored` aspect to try and simplify things.  I get lost when I try to add data to the `list2` variable.  Can anyone help me get this to work properly?

```
stock = {"AAPL", "FB", "BAC", "TWTR", "IBM"};
stocks = {"AAPL", "FB", "BAC", "TWTR", "IBM"};
fields = {"Close", "5ema", "5ema[1]"};
tablefillnew[stock_] :=
 (list = {data = 
       FinancialData[#, "Close", {{DatePlus[-60], DatePlus[-1]}}]; 
      FinancialData[#, "Close"], 
      ema = FinancialIndicator["ExponentialMovingAverage", 5] #;
      t = Take[ema, {1}]; y = Take[ema {2}];} & /@ stock; 
  list2 = Table[{colored[[ii]], list[[ii, 2]]}, {ii, 1, Length[list]}];
  TableForm[list2, TableHeadings -> {stocks, fields}
   ])
tablefillnew[stock]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of syntax errors and general messiness in this code. My proxy server won't let me download `FinancialData` at the moment, so I can't test this completely, but several things you should note:

- intermediate variables should localised using `Module`.
- syntax error: `y = Take[ema {2}]` should be `y = Take[ema, {2}]`  or just `ema[[2]]`.
- `FinancialIndicator["ExponentialMovingAverage", 5] #;` doesn't work that way - it works inside things like `TradingChart`. You are better off just using the built-in `ExponentialMovingAverage`, after stripping off the dates.
- it's no wonder you are confused with all the definitions inside definitions. Try making your code a bit less nested.
- there seems to have been unnecessarily doubled braces in the definition of `data`
- without knowing what `coloured` did, it is hard to work out what to replace it with.

Here is a simplified version that should work. Notice that I have made `fields` a parameter so you can change your preferred functions. I have used [pattern matching](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PatternMatchingFunctions.html) to check that the data you pass to the function are what you expect (lists of strings). I have used `Part` (`[[]]`) instead of `Take` to simplify getting the bits of the exponential moving average.  And instead of building up the table row by row using `Table`, I just use `Transpose`.

```
tablefillnew[stocklist:{__String}, fields:{__String}] :=
 Module[{data, ema, closeprices},
  data = FinancialData[#, "Close", {DatePlus[-60], DatePlus[-1]}] & /@ stocklist;
  closeprices = FinancialData[#, "Close"] & /@ stocklist; 
(* latest close not close for previous day:  they could be different *)
  ema = ExponentialMovingAverage[#[[All, 2]], 5] & /@ data;
  TableForm[Transpose[{closeprices, ema[[All, 1]], ema[[All, 2]]}], 
   TableHeadings -> {stocklist, fields}]]
```

Comment: Hi Verbeia Thank you very much for your reply!  Your rewrite is much clearer as to what the code is doing. :)  I added the issues to a list called stocklist and can't seem to get any output from it.  The colored variable was just coloring blue or green based on whether the price was above or below $20.  But it hurt the clarity of the code too much.

Comment: stocklist = {"AAPL", "FB", "BAC", "TWTR", "IBM"};
fields = {"Close", "5ema", "5ema[1]"};
tablefillnew[stocklist : {__String}, fields : {__String}] := 
 Module[{data, ema, closeprices}, 
  data = FinancialData[#, 
      "Close", {{DatePlus[-60], DatePlus[-1]}}] & /@ stocklist; 
  closeprices = 
   FinancialData[#, "Close"] & /@ 
    stocklist;(*latest close not close for previous day:
  they could be different*)
  ema = ExponentialMovingAverage[#, 5] & /@ data; 
  TableForm[Transpose[{closeprices, ema[[All, 1]], ema[[All, 2]]}], 
   TableHeadings -> {stocklist, fields}]]